# How to get Time in milliseconds & How to add 5 minutes to the milliseconds in mySql

Tags: mysql, datetime

How to get current time in milliseconds & how to add 5 minutes to it in mySql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select unix_timestamp() now, unix_timestamp()+5*60*1000 'After 5 Minutes';

```
NOW          After 5 Minutes
```

1470381500      1470681500

Answer (score 6):

MySQL 5.6.4 has introduced fuller support for [fractional seconds in time values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html). The CURTIME function can now return the current time with up to microseconds. To return it with milliseconds, you call it like this:

```
CURTIME(3)
```

However, that will give you a `time` value, not an integer number of milliseconds that I am assuming you are after. To get the number of milliseconds, you can apply the UNIX_TIMESTAMP function to `CURTIME(3)` and multiply the result by 1000:

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) * 1000
```

The result will be a `decimal` with the scale of 3. You can further cast it to `unsigned` if you need the result to be an actual integer type:

```
CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) * 1000 AS unsigned)
```

So much for the *current* time in milliseconds. As for adding 5 minutes to it, you can add 300,000 to the last result:

```
CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) * 1000 AS unsigned) + 300000
```

Or you can add just 300 (seconds) before the multiplication (similar to Arnel Aves's suggestion):

```
CAST((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3)) + 300) * 1000 AS unsigned)
```

That way the intent might be clearer. But it will probably be even clearer if you add the interval directly to CURTIME:

```
CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURTIME(3) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) * 1000 AS unsigned)
```

---

Additional information:

- [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [Cast Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

I only know of current time **in seconds**

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

And 5 minutes is 60*5 = 300 seconds, so your query will be

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP() + 300;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> SELECT NOW(3), NOW(3) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| NOW(3)                  | NOW(3) + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2016-08-04 14:43:53.738 | 2016-08-04 14:48:53.738    |
+-------------------------+----------------------------+
```